# Recyclerview duplicated items on scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

It seems like this is a pretty common question, but none of the other questions helped me on figuring this out. So, the problem is, I have a recyclerview that is duplicating the items when i scroll. Like this:
[duplicated items.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iLbQ.png)

It looks like there's a fixed list below the scrollable list.
Here's my Adapter:

```
public class FriendsListAdapter extends   RecyclerView.Adapter<FriendsListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Friend> mDataset;
    private Context ctx;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView friendName;
        public ImageView friendPicture;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            friendName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.friendName);
            friendPicture = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.friendPicture);
        }
    }

    public FriendsListAdapter(ArrayList<Friend> myDataset, Context context) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public FriendsListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,    int viewType) {
        View v =   LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.friend_item,   parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.friendName.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
        holder.friendName.setTag(mDataset.get(position));

//
//        if(mDataset.get(position).getImageUrl() != null &&    !mDataset.get(position).getImageUrl().isEmpty()) {
//            holder.friendPicture.setImageBitmap(null);
//
//            Transformation transformation = new       RoundedTransformationBuilder()
//                    .cornerRadiusDp(50)
//                    .oval(false)
//                    .build();
//
//            Picasso.with(ctx)
//                    .load(mDataset.get(position).getImageUrl())
//                    .fit()
//                    .transform(transformation)
//                    .into(holder.friendPicture);
//        }

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

The picasso part is commented because I was testing to see if that was the problem.

Here's my fragment's onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends_list, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mDataset = new ArrayList<>();

    final ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(MyApp.getConfigHelper().getFriends() == null || MyApp.getConfigHelper().getFriends().isEmpty()) {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("fields", "id, name, picture");

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONArray array, GraphResponse response) {
                        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                        if (error == null) {
                            try {
                                Friend pictureByName;
                                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                    values.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                                    JSONObject arrayObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                    JSONObject picObject = arrayObject.getJSONObject("picture");
                                    String fbId = arrayObject.getString("id");
                                    String picUrl = picObject.getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                                    pictureByName = new Friend(fbId, values.get(i), picUrl);
                                    mDataset.add(pictureByName);
                                }

                                Collections.sort(mDataset);
                                MyApp.getConfigHelper().setFriends(mDataset);

                                mAdapter = new FriendsListAdapter(mDataset, getActivity());
                                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
        request.setParameters(params);
        request.executeAsync();
    } else {
        mDataset = MyApp.getConfigHelper().getFriends();
        mAdapter = new FriendsListAdapter(mDataset, getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    return view;
}
```

An this is the frament:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myApp.Activity.FriendsListActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Do you guys have any idea of what's happening?

Comment: Can you try to change `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` ?

Comment: Wow, you're a hero, it worked! Do you know why?? Also, can you make an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to change

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myApp.Activity.FriendsListActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

By:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myApp.Activity.FriendsListActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I think the `RelativeLayout` superimpose each page of your `Recycler`

Comment: Same issue by the way when using a CardView, solved also by turning to a LinearLayout.

Comment: Same issue I got with CardView, solved it by wrapping it in a LinearLayout

Answer (score 5):

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position;
}
```

Comment: You should post answers with some explanation related to the context of the question.This sort of answers is not in line with SO format.Please add more information to your answer.

Answer (score -5):

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position;
}
```

override those method in your adapter class